# JUEL set up doesn't work

Tags: spring, expression, spring-webflow, myfaces, juel

I tried two ways to implement [this](https://github.com/beckchr/juel).

Specs:
MyFaces 2.1.7
javax.el 2.1.0
WebFlow 2.3.1
Spring Framework (OSGI)

First, added the dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.odysseus.juel</groupId>
  <artifactId>juel-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>de.odysseus.juel</groupId>
  <artifactId>juel-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>de.odysseus.juel/groupId>
  <artifactId>juel-spi</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I attached to the manifest.mf of my application the bundles.

Firstly, I tried to use [this old method](http://www.scottbattaglia.com/2008/12/17/spring-web-flow-2-and-juel-integration/) some guy coded. When I try to run it I get this error message:

```
org.springframework.binding.expression.ParserException: Unable to parse expression string '#{extRuntimeAuthorityUserManager.addRuntimeAuthority(conversationScope.accessLayerModel.accessUser, T(com.common.identity.enums.ERuntimeAuthority).AUTHORITY_CHANGE_WORKING_INSTITUTION)}'
```

Secondly, the **most recent** I have found is this [one](http://tandraschko.blogspot.ca/2012/08/increase-your-jsf-application.html). I had some problem with clashing version of javax.el, because juel-api import is own. So, I added in the juel-api manifest this line.

```
Fragment-Host: javax.el
```

Then,

I add the ExpressionImpl from JUEL to MyFaces configuration in the web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.EXPRESSION_FACTORY</param-name>
        <param-value>de.odysseus.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Unfortunatelly, I get this log message:

```
MyFaces Bean Validation support enabled
```

Which tells us that JUEL is not being loaded? what am I missing or doing wrong..

Comment: did you download it from there? that version is read only. download from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/juel/files/juel/juel-2.2/

Comment: instructions to set it up are given in the sourceforge pdf http://juel.sourceforge.net/juel.pdf

Comment: I got mine from here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.odysseus.juel (impl, api and spi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the manifest of javax.el that was being used by my application.

1) Remove the old javax version and replace it with [latest version](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/orbit/javax.el/2.2.0.v201303151357/javax.el-2.2.0.v201303151357.pom) of javax.el from jetty.orbit.
2) Keep the dependency from Juel that I mentionned.
3) Add to your Manifest.mf of your project (webapp) with those bundles

- javax.el.2.2.0.v201303151357
- juel-api
- juel-impl

4) Tricky part: Open the javax.el.2.2.0.v201303151357 and open the manifest of this jar. Then, add this line to force the use of the javax.el from juel-api.

```
Fragment-Host: de.odysseus.juel-api
```